# ubuntu filesystem root low disk space

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, filesystem

I am having a problem with Low disk space in Ubuntu 18.04. Using on terminal:

**`df -h`:**

[image: df -h]

**`sudo du -hs /*`:**

[image: sudo du -hs /*]

I want to take the partition on `/dev/sdb4` and move to `/dev/sdb5`.

[image: gparted screenshot]

Actually I want to solve the problem of low space, I think this is how I can do it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. You can copy the text from a terminal and paste it as text. Format it using `{}` icon.

Comment: Try looking into /var to see what is filling the disk up (probably /var/log - but there could be others).

Comment: It’s not clear what you want to do. You have an install and some user data on sda5. You have very little on sda4 which may be another install given the name. Why not delete sda4 and expand sda5 into that space? Alternatively move the home directory on sda5 to sda4, delete sda5 and expand sda4 into the spare space?

Comment: From what it looks like to me is that you have everything on your `/dev/sda5` and nothing is in use on your `/dev/sda4`.  I see that your `/home` folder is taking up more than 59% of your partition.  I would start there and see if you have tons of files in your `~/Downloads` folder that you could possibly get rid of.